# What does NEQ "NOPROMPT" in .bat file do?

Tags: batch-file

I am reading some .bat files that run some SQL scripts and at some point I see the following code:

```
if /I "%3" NEQ "NOPROMPT" (
    pause
)
```

I looked into finding what does this mean but I can't figure it out. I know that the `%3` is one of the parameters which I initialize at an earlier point but I don't understand what this check does.

Comment: [**N**OT**EQ**UAL*TO*](https://ss64.com/nt/neq.html)

Comment: It tests to see if the third parameter passed is equal to "NOPROMPT", and pauses if it is not. `NEQ` is `NotEQual`.

Comment: run `if /?` and read its output

Comment: As the comparison is for a string it should read `If /I Not "%~3"=="NOPROMPT" Pause` anyhow!

Comment: @Compo In my help the compare-ops EQU NEQ etc require enabledExtensions but are explained: `IF [/I] string1 compare-op string2 command` So IMO there is nothing speaking against it's use. I do prefer it over  Not and == at different places with long variable names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It tests for inequality. `NEQ` is the "not equal to" operator in batch files. `/I` makes the test case-insensitive.